# Point of JSON-RPC vs simpler JSON

Tags: json, json-rpc

this is a JSON-RPC object I am implementing

```
{
         "method":"create",
         "params": [
                     {
                     "nid": "69",
                     "body": 
                                    {
                                    "und": 
                                        [
                                        {
                                        "value":
                                            "blah"
                                        }
                                        ]
                                    }   
                     }
                     ]
        }
```

here is how I would do it with "normal" JSON

```
 {
   "method":"create",
   "id":"69",
   "value":"blah"
 }
```

since JSON is a parsed as a map or dictionary, this should be adequate regardless of the presence of nested JSONArrays and JSON Objects in those arrays, explain why JSON-RPC is better or desired by anything at all

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your JSON-RPC is invalid; id has to be at the top level, as it is in your "normal" JSON
- After correcting for the above, your JSON-RPC is still needlessly complex; params could just be [{"value":"blah"}].  Which would make your "normal" JSON very slightly less complex, but harder to parse (since you couldn't rely on "params" no matter what)
- Your "normal" JSON would not allow for unnamed parameters (ones identified solely by position).  Thus, the minimal added complexity buys you something which you might not need in your application, but others might

Comment: this kind of json-rpc object is what the client's server expects. do you know of a JSON-RPC validator?

Comment: I'm just going by the spec.  So in your case, the answer to your original question may well be "because that's what the client requires".

Comment: do you know of a JSON-RPC validator?